# How to replace special symbol?

Tags: php, xml-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing xml from url php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511687/parsing-xml-from-url-php)

I need to parse xml-document from url and solve to use CURL, because my hosting don't working with some dom or simplexml functions. How I can replace symbol of euro and show them. Function str_replace dont help me.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.aviasales.ru/latest-offers.xml';


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'app');

$query = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml=simplexml_load_string($query);
//$xml = str_replace('&euro;', '€', $xml);
?>

<table width=100%>

    <tr bgcolor="#CAE8F0" align="left">
        <td><b><?= $xml->offer[1]['title']?></b></td>
       <td width=5%><b><a href="<?=$xml->offer[1]["href"]?>">buy</a></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I showed you how to this, but you could not understand! What you want more? Let's go to your desk and write the best code for you... OK? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511687/parsing-xml-from-url-php

Answer (score 1):

`str_replace` as you figured out wont work on an object. However if you are outputting this to html, you can leave entities as is.

If you need to decode it, run your properties, not the entire object, through `html_entity_decode`.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, $xml is not a string, but a SimpleXMLElement. You can probably replace the € entity before you load the string:

```
$xml = simplesml_load_string(str_replace('&euro;', '€', $query));
```

as long as $query is encoded with multibyte characters you should be all right. If not, you will likely have to traverse $xml.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to edit the XML directly using SimpleXML:

> The SimpleXML extension provides a very simple and easily usable toolset to convert XML to an object that can be processed with normal property selectors and array iterators. *http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php*

You will have to use PHP DOM extension:

> The DOM extension allows you to operate on XML documents through the DOM API with PHP 5. *http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.dom.php*

### Example:

```
// Create
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;

// Load
if(is_file($filePath))
    $doc->load($filePath);
else
    $doc->loadXML('<rss version="2.0"><channel><title></title><description></description><link></link></channel></rss>');

// Update nodes content
$doc->getElementsByTagName("title")->item(0)->nodeValue = 'Foo';
$doc->getElementsByTagName("description")->item(0)->nodeValue = 'Bar';
$doc->getElementsByTagName("link")->item(0)->nodeValue = 'Baz';
```

Example by combining question and chosen answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6001937/358906